# Oracle MONTHS_BETWEEN to return a whole number

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have an Oracle `Select` statement, and inside it I have the following:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN(CON.F_CON_END_DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) MONTHSTOEXPIRE,
```

The aim of that code is to get me the number of months between two dates. It does work, but it returns them in a way that is breaking my VB.NET code. Something about an overflow exception!

It returns `1.83870967741935` and I expect a `2`?

What can I do to make my query return the nearest whole number for the `MONTHSTOEXPIRE` value?

Comment: To really answer this correctly you need to specify how you get from 1.8 to 2. It could be ROUND or CEIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you simply need to use the round() function?

```
ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(CON.F_CON_END_DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE)), 0) MONTHSTOEXPIRE
```

It works on my Oracle.

Let me know if it works on yours!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

- [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx),

  > Rounds a value to the nearest integer or to the specified number of fractional digits.
- [Math.Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx)

  > Returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the specified number.
- [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx).

  > Returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number.

Answer (score 0):

use like this
round(MONTHS_BETWEEN('29-Jun-2014', TRUNC(SYSDATE))) MONTHSTOEXPIRE
since you cannot always get exact month count, you can get the exact value and round it to the nearest integer